# Non linear, non-homogenous 1. order initial value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Given the $D :=\{(t,x)\in \mathbb{R}^2:t^2+x^2<1\}$ and $f:D\to\mathbb{R}, \, f(t,x)=\sqrt{1-t^2-x^2}$. I should proof that there exists a unique maximum soulution $x:(a,b)\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $-\infty<a<0<b<\infty$ to the IVP $x'=f(t,x), \, x(0)=0$. 
Furthermore I am supposed to show that $\lim_{x\to a}x(t)$ exists in $\mathbb{R}$ and $-a=b,\, b^2+x^2(b)=1$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\leq b<1$.
The uniqueness of the solution follows by the theorem of Picard-Lindelöf, so that's the easy part. Also, $a,b$ can't be infinty since the function $f$ is only defined on $D$ and for that $t\in (-1,1)$ but I cannot work it out any further.  I guess the existence of the limits follow by the theorem of the boundary values (sorry if that's not the correct english term). Any advice would be helpful.